# How to calculate quarterly averages from daily data with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have daily data from 01.01.1990. to 31.12.2012. I need to calculate quarterly averages from the daily data with a VBA function. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try `WorksheetFunction.Average`, `WorksheetFunction.AverageIf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your data in a pivot table. Put your Date values in the Rows and put your numeric values in the `Values`. Right click on the date data and select `Group...`

[image: Group by quarters/years]

To make sure you are taking the average right click on your numeric data and select `Value Field Settings`

[image: Value Field Settings-->Average]

You'll get something that looks like this

[image: final output. quarters and group by year. show average.]